# Resize a UiTextField/UiTextView to fit content when button pressed

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uitextview

I have been searching for hours and I can't find any solution.

I want to make a UITextField or UITextView (don't care whichever one works) display the word
"Contacts..." in a single line, then when i press a button, the textfield should grow to fit all of the content. Ideally I want to have all of the components on my view move down to accommodate the larger text field.

I have seen this technique in tons of apps but I cannot find a solution! There must be some GitHub library with a UITextField that has this behaviour.

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar need a while back, and made a category to support resizing of each `UITextView`. Just add this category to your project, import it to the class that you need it in, and call `autoAdjustHeight` on your `UITextView` when you want to resize it.

UITextView+Resizeable.h:

```
@interface UITextView (Resizeable)

-(void)autoAdjustHeight;

@end
```

UITextView+Resizeable.m:

```
#import "UITextView+Resizeable.h"

@implementation UITextView (Resizeable)

-(void)autoAdjustHeight {

    CGFloat fixedWidth = self.frame.size.width;
    CGSize newSize = [self sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(fixedWidth, MAXFLOAT)];
    CGRect newFrame = self.frame;
    newFrame.size = CGSizeMake(fmaxf(newSize.width, fixedWidth), newSize.height);
    self.frame = newFrame;
    self.scrollEnabled = NO;
}

@end
```